# Make a button change meta_value

Tags: meta-value, buttons

I would like if someone could point me in the right direction for doing this.
Each post frontend should have a button that changes the database value on/off if the user is logged in.
Ie.: post_id: 685, meta_key: switch-01, meta_value: off
Clicking the button changes meta_value to on, but only for 2 minutes, then automatically reverts back to off in the database.

At the same time when clicked, I would like a hidden "timer" or message in the frontend under the button to become visible on click and count down ie. 2 minutes to 0.

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: Please explain **why** you want to do it that way. It could be that you are facing a [XY Problem](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: A physical device will be communicating with the database and this button will eventually turn a switch on. The device keeps checking meta_value and does nothing until it sees "on", could also be true/false, 0/1, as there is no other status. The reason for reverting after two minutes is that the device only reads, does not write, therefore cannot change the meta_value and this is basically a failsafe.

Comment: "A physical device" ... that could be anything. Example: A Hammer.

Comment: Please read the link "XY Problem" (1st comment) and file an [edit] with all your info. Thanks.